# jqgrid will not load json data from remote URL

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid set up in jsFiddle:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
            height: 700,  
            width: 900,  
            datatype: 'json', 
            mtype:'GET',
            url: url,
            colNames:['Col 1','Col 2'],
            colModel :[ 
              {name:'col1', index:'col1'},
              {name:'col2', index:'col2'},
            ],
            pager: '#pager_list',
            rowNum:20,
            rowList:[20,50,100],
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Test',
            gridview : true,    
           });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rw5hogz3/11

However, it will not load json data from the remote URL. The json seems fine when loaded in a browser.

It does work however when I host both the jqgrid and json script on localhost. Has anyone experienced something like this before? Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Youre getting a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  This means you need to setup CORS properly on your server

Comment: change the datatype to jsonp

Comment: That did the trick, thank you both so much!

Comment: http://202.137.146.116/tokoweblink/weblink.php?q=1&agent=ABVT0010&rows=100&page=1   has no data

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS on your server.
Put this on the page that is returning the JSON

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

If you're using a framework, this will be slightly more complicated.

But just google CORS, to learn more.

Also, you might try madalins suggestion of jsonp datatype.  But in jqgrid, its not as simple as just typing 'jsonp' into datatype.  you need to do it in the ajaxGridOptions...

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
            height: 700,  
            width: 900,  
            datatype: 'json', 
            ajaxGridOptions: { jsonp: true, contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }, 
            mtype:'GET',
            // rest of your code
```

This likely wont work though, as you still will likely get some sort of CORS error

Answer (score 0):

Try Jsonp for Cross - Requesting

Use

```
    $("#list").jqGrid({
                height: 700,  
                width: 900,  
                datatype: 'json', 
                mtype:'GET',
                url: "http://202.137.146.116/tokoweblink/weblink.php?q=1&agent=ABVT0010",
                ajaxGridOptions: { jsonp: true, contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                colNames:['Inv No', 'Client', 'Amount'],
                colModel:[
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
                        {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
                        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"}
                        ],
                 });
```

Assign column Model name,index with json key val.